# Control content of node module when included as dependency by a project

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gruntjs, package.json

Let's say I have a node project 'A' with a JS file, 10 resource files and some test files.

There is another project 'B' which depends on the JS file of project 'A'. So, it includes it as dependency in package.json as:

```
"dependencies": {
    "A": "git+https://github.com/repo/A.git"
}
```

But this will also try to fetch all unwanted files like resources and test files of project 'A' in *node_modules* folder.

Is there a way I can control in package.json of 'A' that which files to expose if included as dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe .npmignore is what you need. Please see [Keeping files out of your package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package)